# Xubuntu 20.04 Automatic Ubiquity - Installing Additional Packages

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, ubiquity

I'm trying to install `openssh-server` on Xubuntu 20.04 with Automatic Ubiquity Installator. According to https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs04.html point "B.4.11. Package selection", I can use

```
ubiquity pkgsel/include string openssh-server
```

which does not work (openssh server is not installed).

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation I can use `ubiquity/success_command` (or `preseed/late_command`) to run own commands... So I tried something like this:

```
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
    echo 'engineer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/99_engineer; \
    chmod 440 /target/etc/sudoers.d/99_engineer; \
    chroot /target apt-get update; \
    chroot /target apt-get install -y openssh-server
```

Also not working. Which is funny, because sudoers lines seems to work - only openssh-server is not installed...

What I'm doing wrong? What Ubuntu 20.04 changed and not documented anywhere? Because all examples on entire Internet about Ubuntu 18.04 says that above should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I dived into the Ubiquity source code used in Ubuntu 20.04 and it seems that developers have removed such features like `pkgsel/include`. Ubuntu documentation is silent about that. Also, I confirmed that `preseed/late_command` is not fired. The only thing working is `ubiquity/success_command`. I don't know if it was like that from the very beginning, but `success_command` is run with `sh -c "commands here"`, which from my testing means that you are not able to run scripts inside `ubiquity/success_command`. After really long tinkering around, my final (working) solution is using cron to create a command after reboot, which will wait for Internet access (by checking `8.8.8.8`):

```sh
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
    mkdir -p /mnt/floppy; \
    mount -t vfat /dev/fd0 /mnt/floppy; \
    cp /mnt/floppy/sudoers /target/etc/sudoers.d/99_engineer; \
    chmod 440 /target/etc/sudoers.d/99_engineer; \
    mkdir -p /target/root; \
    cp /mnt/floppy/firstboot.sh /target/root/firstboot.sh; \
    chmod 750 /target/root/firstboot.sh; \
    echo '@reboot root bash /root/firstboot.sh >> /var/log/firstboot.log 2>&1' >> /target/etc/crontab;
```

Note that I have also used here `floppy_files` from Packer - this is why I can use `/dev/fd0`.

`sudoers` file:

```
engineer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

`firstboot.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Waiting for Internet ..."
while ! timeout 0.2 ping -c 1 -n 8.8.8.8 &> /dev/null
do
    printf "%c" "."
done
echo "OK"

# Instal SSH Server
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install openssh-server

# Remove from crontab
sed -i '/firstboot/d' /etc/crontab
```

Btw, huge minus for all people responsible for removing `pkgsel/include` and other changes, which are documented everywhere and currently does not work in `automatic-ubiquity`, and which allowed in an easy manner to install extra stuff needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had struggled with this issue for server days until I found the answer. Apparently the installer shuts down the network interface at the end of the installation. You need to bring the network interface up to allow network access so it can download the apps. Try this but change the interface name ens160 to match yours.

ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string 
string ip link set up dev ens160; 
dhclient ens160; 
apt-get update -y; 
in-target apt-get install -y openssh-server;

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me :(